# tumblr embeds creating blank space on pages

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-html

third time lucky. embed links, videos, songs, whatever, look fine as actual posts on tumblr.com/mycomaboyfriend but on mycomaboyfriend.tumblr, thats when they start to glitch out and create large gaps of empty space on the post.

ive gone through code but im not great at coding so i cant figure out whatd fix it or cause the issue, all i know really is that it has something to do with tumblr changing how embed stuff works.

[post example 1](https://mycomaboyfriend.tumblr.com/post/716477935481126912/nicole-dollanganger-coma-baby) [post example 2](https://mycomaboyfriend.tumblr.com/post/713443973800263681/roar-christmas-kids) and [tumblr page](https://mycomaboyfriend.tumblr.com/)

Comment: Possible to include some code, or even better a working fiddle?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.